# addEventListener is not a function simple code pasted from Khan ACA

Tags: javascript, html

**Screenshot**

[image]

Im a begginer of Javascript and its a bit obvious what im trying to do, its a simple code but it tells me always 2 things, `addEventListener`enter code here` is not a function" and "add event listener undefined" tried Loops, tried changing Elements for Element tried telling which from the elements is fromm [number (i know first is cero)], changed place of script, and tried giving boolean values to face, Help.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Code is text, just copy paste it into your question, there is no reason to make an image of it

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a html collection ... not an html element - you either copied the code wrong, or made uninformed changes, or the Khan Academy is rubbifh

Comment: Nope, i writethe code with all the classes that I was using

Comment: and Tried to Element instead of Elements

Answer (score 0):

Don't paste screenshots of code, paste your actual code instead.

The problem is that `getElementsByClassName` returns an *HTMLCollection*, not a single element, so you can't assign a listener to the collection: select a single element first.

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Try something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.alex').forEach((alex) => {
  alex.addEventListener('mousemove', () => document.querySelector('.pipo').textContent += 'mooove';
});
```

Note that `NodeList.forEach` is something new-ish, supported as of the past few years - to support ancient browsers, use a plain `for` loop or a polyfill. (array methods are generally superior to `for` loops: no manual iteration, better abstraction, function parameters)

Comment: Thx dude!, so if i change from my code only my ElementsBy for QuerySelector will it still work? or i have to loop it like that?

Comment: You put a `for` loop in there, so I assumed you were trying to iterate over every `.Alex` (though I only see one of them in your HTML? if you're only ever going to have one, then yes, use querySelector instead)